# Proving elements in a set can be expressed in a certain form.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I'm going to be as vague as possible while trying to provide enough details.

I have a set which is defined by certain conditions, one of them being that for any two values x,y in the set, we have that $\frac{x+y}{2}$ is also in the set.

When I write out the values of the set, I found that each value can be expressed in the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$, where n,m are non-negative integers.

If I wanted to prove that every element in the set can be expressed as such, how would I do so?

I'm assuming it would be inductively, but I'm not sure what the inductive step would be. Showing $n+1$ wouldn't exactly work, because the next value is not necessarily of a denominator $2^{n+1}$.

My next thought is to assume there are two arbitrary values a,b and then put them through the condition above ($\frac{a+b}{2}$), with a and b each expressed in the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$, then show that the result can be expressed in the same form $\frac{m}{2^n}$. Would this work?

Comment: Although your details are vague, roughly from what you've said, I would say that you can't conclude that every element of your set takes this form. I'm guessing you're looking at midpoint convexity here. While the set $\{m/2^n : m, n \in \Bbb{N}, m \le 2^n\}$ is a midpoint convex set containing $0$ and $1$ (here $0 \in \Bbb{N}$), there are other, larger midpoint convex sets with the same property, e.g. $[0, 1]$. It contains irrational numbers, which certainly are not of this form.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what midpoint convexity is. I also apologize, I failed to mention that x and y are non-negative rational numbers.

Comment: Assuming that every element could indeed be expressed as $m/2^n$, how would we move forward from there?

Comment: OK, my guess was wrong. But, even restricting to rational numbers, you still can't necessarily conclude this. Basically, $m/2^n$ are all the numbers you can "generate" starting with $0$ and $1$, and applying this $(x + y)/2$ rule. You can prove this by induction on the number of times the rule is applied. But, just assuming that the set is closed under taking midpoints (which is the very definition of midpoint convexity, by the way), does not mean there aren't *other* points in there too, e.g. $1/3$. It will generate even more points, while the $(x + y)/2$ rule still holds.

Comment: Wait, aren't you trying to prove that every element can be expressed as $m/2^n$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to prove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148892/discussion-between-marko-and-theo-bendit).

Comment: Rational numbers which can be expressed as fractions with a power of $2$ as the denominator are called "dyadic rationals", and include all integers, since $1$ is a power of $2$. It is true that the average of two dyadic rationals is also a dyadic rational. But the average of a dyadic rational and a non-dyadic rational will be non-dyadic. So the average condition doesn't tell us anything by itself. If you are getting nothing but dyadics, it is because whatever is determining the set is selecting nothing but dyadics. As you did not specify how they are determined, we cannot say why.